# Hibernate save() function in MQ listener flow persists only after listener execution completes

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, ibm-mq

Consider the code snippet below. The MQ listener does 2 activities - 1. Persist the object received in MQ 2. Send APNS notification to 100 devices.

```
      @JmsListener(destination = "${mq.queue.name}")
      public void receiveMessage(String user) throws IOException {
        try {
            UserDetailsVO userObject = mapper.readValue(user, UserDetailsVO.class);
            String result=persistUserDetails(userObject);           
            if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                userService.sendAPNS(); //Sends notification to 100 devices
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            logger.error(Error processing MQ message);      
        }
    }
    
    public String persistUserDetails(UserDetailsVO userObject) {
        userDao.save(); // Using hibernate method
        return "success";
    }

    public void sendAPNS() {
       // sending APNS to devices
    }
```

Here eventhough the persistUserDetails() function called before sendAPNS(), the user object is not persisted immediately in the database. Instead, it waits for the sendAPNS() to finish the activity and then the data is persisted in table. My need is to persist immediately the user details than waiting for the entire execution completes. What changes should I make?

The JPA configuration properties are given below:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
```

Comment: Maybe changing the propagation level of the transaction in `persistUserDetails()` will help you, I mean REQIURED_NEW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the SQL statements to be sent to the database, you can call `entityManager.flush()` after persisting. But still the transaction will not be comitted until the full executioms finishes.

If you need the database transaction to be committed before sending the messages you need to wrap the persist call within a service that starts a new transaction. In an EJB for example that would be method with transaction attribute `REQUIRES_NEW`.

Comment: I have added @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) for persistUserDetails() function and its working as expected. Will there be any performance impact due to this change?